# How can I open a web page from inside my app?

Tags: android, browser, android-webview, android-browser

I've found an app's source code and it opens web pages using external browsers, like Chrome or others. I want to make it access those pages from inside the app, without using an external browser. I think that I should change the code below somehow, but I don't know how.

```
private class MyWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://dmc.teiion.gr")) {
            //open url contents in webview
            return false;
        } else {
            //here open external links in external browser or app
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
yourWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Or change:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

to

```
view.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: thanks sir. that did work for me. also i have another question if u know. in a menu item when you open the page seems to be like desktop mode-version. i tried to write the url as m.@@@@.com but the page doesnt support it. any way to fix this? i have a screenshot here http://prntscr.com/mj8v8c

Comment: i tried this but no helped //WebView
        mwebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mwebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mwebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");

Comment: If you have a new question, dont post it here.. Create a new question

Comment: i cant says every 90 mins. thats why sir. can you provide some help? i looked many  posts no help